# Java exception: When running with master 'yarn' either HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR must be set in the environment

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, geomesa

I built the jupyter/pyspark-notebook Docker image. I installed geomesa_pyspark and tried to run the following example commands from the official guide.

```
import geomesa_pyspark

conf = geomesa_pyspark.configure(
    jars=['/usr/local/spark/jars/geomesa-accumulo-spark-runtime_2.11-2.0.0.jar'],
    packages=['geomesa_pyspark','pytz'],
    spark_home='/usr/local/spark/').\
    setAppName('MyTestApp')

conf.get('spark.master')

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = ( SparkSession
    .builder
    .config(conf=conf)
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()
)
```

The same problem persists.

```
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-eca73e557583> in <module>
     22 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
     23 
---> 24 spark = ( SparkSession
     25     .builder
     26     .config(conf=conf)

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in getOrCreate(self)
    226                             sparkConf.set(key, value)
    227                         # This SparkContext may be an existing one.
--> 228                         sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
    229                     # Do not update `SparkConf` for existing `SparkContext`, as it's shared
    230                     # by all sessions.

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/context.py in getOrCreate(cls, conf)
    382         with SparkContext._lock:
    383             if SparkContext._active_spark_context is None:
--> 384                 SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
    385             return SparkContext._active_spark_context
    386 

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/context.py in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    142                 " is not allowed as it is a security risk.")
    143 
--> 144         SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
    145         try:
    146             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/context.py in _ensure_initialized(cls, instance, gateway, conf)
    329         with SparkContext._lock:
    330             if not SparkContext._gateway:
--> 331                 SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
    332                 SparkContext._jvm = SparkContext._gateway.jvm
    333 

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py in launch_gateway(conf, popen_kwargs)
    106 
    107             if not os.path.isfile(conn_info_file):
--> 108                 raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
    109 
    110             with open(conn_info_file, "rb") as info:

Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

In the logs on Portainer instead I read this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: When running with master 'yarn' either HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR must be set in the environment.
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.error(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:631)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.validateSubmitArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.validateArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.<init>(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2$$anon$3.<init>(SparkSubmit.scala:1013)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.parseArguments(SparkSubmit.scala:1013)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1030)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I think the JAVA_HOME is set correctly (JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64"). From the logs I guess that HADOOP_HOME should also be set, but despite the fact that the installed Hadoop version is shown in the Docker image specifications, when I run the container I can't find Hadoop anywhere.
One way thing is that if I run the same commands from the pyspark shell instead of from the Notebook, it runs correctly without errors.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what version of Spark and GeoMesa you installed, but at a minimum you will need to:

1. Align the Spark version with a [supported version](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/user/spark/index.html)
2. Ensure that the Scala version is the same between GeoMesa and Spark (probably _2.12)
3. Ensure that the `jars` path in you code is pointing to the correct GeoMesa jar for the version you installed
4. Use JDK 8, as GeoMesa currently requires JDK 8.

Comment: I installed Java 8, I added hdfs to the Docker Compose stack and set the related environment variables. The rest I think is ok. A new error has arisen.
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.net.ConnectException: Call From 2bc1a5523504 / 172.20.0.3 to 0.0.0.0:8032 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused